# how to use tns entries with macromedia drivers for Oracle

Tags: oracle, jdbc, coldfusion, tnsnames

We are currently forced to use macromedia drivers on ColdFusion in order to connect to Oracle databases. The jdbc connection url is like:

```
jdbc:macromedia:oracle://server:port;sid=service
```

The flip side of this approach is that it forces us to 'hard code' the name of the database server as well as the port number and the service name.

Does anyone know how the jdbc url should be to make use of the TNSNames entry?

For OCI drivers, it is `jdbc:oracle:oci:@tnsentry`

Is it possible to do the same with macromedia drivers? what you be the correct url?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We just figured out that the following syntax works:

```
jdbc:macromedia:oracle:TNSNamesFile=C:\\Oracle\\product\\11.2.0\\client_1\\network\\admin\\tnsnames.ora; TNSServerName=tnsentry
```