# Can ColdFusion 8 Use TNS Names

Tags: oracle, coldfusion, coldfusion-8

Can ColdFusion 8 use TNS names for database connectivity to an Oracle 11g instance? If so, could someone point me to the source document explaining how it's done?

Thanks.

Comment: I searched for [+"coldfusion" +"oracle" +"tns"](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%2B%22coldfusion%22+%2B%22oracle%22+%2B%22tns%22) and this comes up: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9402546/how-to-use-tns-entries-with-macromedia-drivers-for-oracle - is it relevant?

Comment: Looks like Peter's link will work for you. I'm curious though, what's the motivation for using a TNS entry for connecting to Oracle? We use CF&Oracle and avoid using TNSNames, as we prefer managing the connection direct in CF

Comment: Thanks for your input. The use of TNS names was mandated way above my pay grade. So, we have to make the switch. Thanks for the link Peter! I'll try that today and see how it goes.

Comment: I tried this JDBC URL:

jdbc:oracle:thin:TNSNamesFile=/folder1/folder2/folder3/folder4/tnsnames.ora; TNSServerName=MyTNSName

But, I got the error:
The Network Adapter could not establish the connection